# TypeError: Cannot read property 'identity' of null Javascript Neo4J data

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, ejs

maybe you can help me with this issue. I´m trying to code in my js app a get request to a Neo4J database and send this data to a ejs page. The problem is that when my request gets nothing (null) it blocks me all the code with an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'identity' of null". The only what I´m looking for, is when no data are retrieved nothing should happen without throwing any errors... only continuing with the rest of the code, but I don´t know how to handle this "null".

```js
app.get('/page/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  
      session
      .run("OPTIONAL MATCH(a:Person)-[r]-(b) WHERE id(a)=toInteger($idParam) RETURN b", {
      idParam:id
      })
      .then(function(result2){
          var RelationArr = [];
          result2.records.forEach(function(record){

            RelationArr.push({

              id: record._fields[0].identity.low,
              name: record._fields[0].properties.name,
              title: record._fields[0].properties.title,
      });
      });

      res.render('person', {
          relation: RelationArr,
      });
      })

      .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the value exists before accessing props.

```js
app.get('/page/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  
      session
      .run("OPTIONAL MATCH(a:Person)-[r]-(b) WHERE id(a)=toInteger($idParam) RETURN b", {
      idParam:id
      })
      .then(function(result2){
          var RelationArr = [];
          result2.records.forEach(function(record){
            if(record._fields[0]) {
              RelationArr.push({
                id: record._fields[0].identity.low,
                name: record._fields[0].properties.name,
                title: record._fields[0].properties.title,
              });
           }
      });

      res.render('person', {
          relation: RelationArr,
      });
      })

      .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });
      })
```

Comment: No, the value doesn´t exist and it´s right so. "Null" is what I expected as value and it should be null in some cases, because there is no entry in the database that match the conditions requested. My problem is that I don´t know how to handle it.

Comment: The code should be something like this: if it´s null, nothing should be render to "page", else should be res.render to "page".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the javascript code to handle the null, I changed the Neo4J query to avoid a "null" value:

```
MATCH(a)-[r]-(b) WHERE id(a)=toInteger($idParam) OPTIONAL MATCH (a) WHERE id(a)=toInteger($idParam) RETURN b
```

Thank you @CaptEmulation your contribution gave me the hint to look to the outcome of the query.